# window.scrollTo is not working on my android Chrome

Tags: android, html, scrolltop, address-bar

i am trying to make a web app, and i need to hide the adress bar.
i read a lot of solution, but they are all try to use "window.scrollTo".

However, window.scrollTo is just NOT WORKING AT ALL in my android which using chorme.

here is the user agent :

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; MI 2 Build/JRO03L) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.64 Mobile Safari/537.36

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1024, user-scalable=0"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    makeContent();
    hideAddressBar();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
   checkScroll()
   setTimeout( function(){ checkScroll() }, 20 );
})

function makeContent(){
  $('body').append("<ul>");
  for (i=1; i<=100 ;i++){
      newHTML = "<li>row"+i+"</li>";
      $('body').append(newHTML);
    }
  $('body').append("</ul>");    
}

function checkScroll(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 1)window.scrollTo(0,2);
}

function hideAddressBar(){
  if(!window.location.hash){
      if(document.height < window.outerHeight){
          document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
      }
      setTimeout( function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 50 );
  }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: my code window.scrollTo(0, 100)
the code and the "scroll to solution" is tested and work nice at the default browser, but not at the chorme.

Comment: Add your code to your question, dont post your code in your comment. And provide more code which needs to be present in order to see what the problem is. The one liner wont help us, help you!